# Trouble Connecting Flutter App to Local Appwrite Server on macOS

Tags: flutter, localhost, flutter-dependencies, endpoint, appwrite

I am experiencing difficulties connecting my Flutter app to a locally hosted Appwrite server on my macOS machine. Despite trying various endpoint configurations, I cannot establish a connection. Here are the details of my setup and what I have tried so far:

Setup:

MacBook pro running the Appwrite server.
Flutter app running on the same macOS machine (macbook pro).
The Appwrite server is configured to listen on port 8080.

What I've Tried:

Setting the endpoint URL to http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1.
Trying http://localhost:8080/v1.
Using the macOS hostname (http://(macos hostname).local:8080/v1).
Ensuring that the Appwrite server is running and listening on port 8080.

Despite these attempts, I still cannot establish a connection between my Flutter app and the local Appwrite server.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to successfully connect a Flutter app to a locally hosted Appwrite server on macOS? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Appwrite's docker tool for installation. To access the server, try hitting http://localhost/ without any port.

Reference -https://dev.to/hackmamba/create-a-local-appwrite-instance-in-3-steps-19n9